# Adding Text to CCSprite

Tags: ios4, cocos2d-iphone

How to add Text to CCSprite Object. I Have 7 Sprite objects now i want to add text to that Sprite Objects with different Text. and how to change that text.

Help me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

E.g. for one sprite:

```
//Make a CCLabelTFF
        CCLabelTTF *label1 = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"text1" fontName:@"Arial" fontSize:25];

//add it to the sprite

[sprite1 addChild: label1];
```

If you need to create many labels than I would prefer to use a CCLabelBMFont (better performence)

```
        CCLabelBMFont* labelBMF1 = [CCLabelBMFont labelWithString:@"text1" fntFile:@"fntfile.fnt"];

[sprite1 addChild: labelBMF1];
```

Comment: and how to wrap the label when large text(For e.g.: 100 characters) is to be add to sprite....

Comment: there are some wrapping methods in the latest cocos2d version (1.0.1). You should look at the Label Test in the cocos2d project.